# Android checkbox click area issue

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a LinearLayout and I programmatically add to it checkboxes from exist layout like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
layout.addView(checkBox);
```

The checkbox `layout_width` attribute is `wrap_content` so the click area supposed to be only the box and the text, except that what really happens is that even the right side that there is nothing there (the parent layout) also clickable and affects the checkbox what I do not want to happen.

(The check box parent layout - LinearLayout has `layout_width:"match_parent"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I infalted the check box even though it have in the layout (xml file) wrap content in the layout_width attribute, for some reason it's still match parent so I had to programmatically set the LayoutParams width to wrap content.

that's it.

Thanks to all those who tried..